# Error: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 23) while Build on GitHub Actions

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, github-actions

When compiling my Android application using GitHub Actions, I am getting the following error:

```
Call requires API level 24 (current min is 23): java.lang.Iterable#forEach [NewApi]
        entryValues.forEach { entryValue ->
```

[image: Image of Error For Reference]

##### **This is my build action yml file**

```
name: Android CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Fetch Sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: zulu
          java-version: '11'

      - name: Setup Android SDK
        uses: android-actions/setup-android@v2

      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
          gradle-version: 7.4

      - name: Setup Gradle Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.gradle/caches
            ~/.gradle/wrapper
          key: >-
            ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*') }}-${{
            hashFiles('**/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties') }}-${{
            hashFiles('**/buildSrc/**/*.kt') }}

      - name: Execute Gradle build
        run: ./gradlew build
```

##### **This is my app level gradle configuration**

```
compileSdk 33

minSdk 23

targetSdk 33

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'    
}
```

##### **This is my Project Level Gradle configuration**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

##### **Settings Gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'app/libs'
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Project"
include ':app'
```

#### Above Gradle Configuration are working fine and build is working successfully on my PC.

Above Gradle Configuration are working fine and build is working successfully on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

try Changing

```
minSdk 23
```

to

```
minSdk 24
```